# Why are my circle cells in my table different sizes?

Tags: html, css, html-table, geometry, cells

I'm trying to make all my cells in my table the same size circles. I've used border radius and I've given them all the same set width, height, margin etc. I could be over looking something in my code that is making this happen but if anyone can figure it out would be of great help!

My html for the table:

```
<table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td id="whitecircle">Mon</td>
<td id="whitecircle">Tue</td>
<td id="whitecircle">Wed</td>
<td id="whitecircle">Thur</td>
<td id="whitecircle">Fri</td>
<td id="whitecircle">Sat</td>
<td id="whitecircle">Sun</td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>21</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>28</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My CSS for the table:

```
table{
height: 320px;
width: 400px;
}

#whitecircle {
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 50%;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;}

td {background-color: red;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align: center;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;}
```

This is for a web design assignment, hence why I'm trying to get it exact :)

Comment: ...a web design assignment suggested you use tables for this!? Also you can't re-use ID's...only one use per page.

Comment: Ya they did unfortunately :/

Comment: Don't use tables, and explain why, for extra points.

Comment: If this is for an assignment, shouldn't you be doing it on your own???

Comment: @DRD Your right but I have been reading through my notes and fiddling around with code for the past 2 hours but couldn't figure out why my cells were different size so needed to get outside help!

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  The only thing I would suggest is using extra markup within each `td` and then formatting these sections to make the circles look...well like circles: http://jsfiddle.net/dszLde14/.

Comment: You can not use the same id name for more than one element so change whitecircle to a class and choose a different id for each one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can't re-use IDs on a page so I have used a class instead.

Try using `table-layout: fixed;`

[**MDN Link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

> **fixed** :
>   Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h47kdmkv/)

```css
table {
    height: 320px;
    width: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.whitecircle {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
td {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td class="whitecircle">Mon</td>
        <td Class="whitecircle">Tue</td>
        <td class="whitecircle">Wed</td>
        <td class="whitecircle">Thur</td>
        <td class="whitecircle">Fri</td>
        <td class="whitecircle">Sat</td>
        <td class="whitecircle">Sun</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice one @Paulie_D +1

Comment: Thank you Paulie this worked also! Never knew that about the ID tag, I will remember that from now on

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `calc()`:

```css
table {
  height: 320px;
  width: calc(175px + 50%);/*here use calc*/
}
#whitecircle {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
td {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td id="whitecircle">Mon</td>
    <td id="whitecircle">Tue</td>
    <td id="whitecircle">Wed</td>
    <td id="whitecircle">Thu</td>
    <td id="whitecircle">Fri</td>
    <td id="whitecircle">Sat</td>
    <td id="whitecircle">Sun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**References**

[calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)